# Why when doing a Monte Carlo Simulation using the inverse normal giving me the same answer as just using the normal?

Tags: normal-distribution, monte-carlo

So I am trying to solve a risk problem using Monte Carlo and the inverse normal. After doing 5000 simulations of invNorm$(x,\mu,\sigma)$ where $x$ is a random number from 0 to 1. And then I count to see how many of those 5000 simulations are less than or equal to a requirement of .95 to get a risk score. The thing I am trying to understand is if I just use the cdf Norm$(.95,\mu,\sigma)$, I roughly get the same answer. Why does that happen? And should I just do the normal distribution instead and not have to run 5000 simulations? or is their a better approach?

Comment: It might be easier to understand if you posted your code.

Comment: There is something called the [inverse Gaussian distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_Gaussian_distribution) which is not this

Comment: Your simulation method essentially gives you an approximation to $0.95$, which seems unnecessary since you can directly find the $95\%$ quantile of a normal distribution.  But it might be useful if you did not have a inverse CDF to use but found some other way of simulating values from your distribution.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, the proportion of samples below $0.95$ is an approximation of the cumulative distribution at that value.

Given a distribution with cumulative distribution function $F$, and given $X \sim \textrm{Uniform}[0, 1]$, then $F^{-1}(X)$, where $F^{-1}$ is the inverse of $F$, has that distribution. Effectively, $X$ is the generated quantile, and applying $F^{-1}$ finds the value associated with that quantile.

In your case, $F \equiv \Phi$ is the normal cumulative distribution function, and (I assume) `invNorm` is just $\Phi^{-1}$, so your samples of $\Phi^{-1}(X)$ are samples from the given normal distribution. The expected proportion of samples below a threshold $t$ is therefore
$$\mathbb{E}([\Phi^{-1}(X) \leq t]; \mu, \sigma) = \mathbb{E}([X \leq \Phi(t)]; \mu, \sigma) = \Phi(t; \mu, \sigma).$$